# How to show one column or the other in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my table I am storing owner's information. Owners can have either name or nationaliy or both.

I have to query the database, which checks if name exists and then take name or else the nationality.

Currently I am using below query:

```
SELECT id,name,nationality FROM owners
```

it's ok but I want name or nationality under single column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general syntax for what you call a "custom column" is `*expression* AS *column_name*`. For example `1 AS one` will give you a column called "one" whose value is always the integer "1". What you need to do is create an expression that evaluates to either `name` or `nationality`, and give that expression a column name.

Assuming you store empty names as `NULL`, you can use:

```sql
SELECT id, COALESCE(name, nationality) AS name_or_nationality FROM owners
```

If empty names are stored as empty strings, you need to use some another construct:

```sql
SELECT id, CASE WHEN name THEN name ELSE nationality END AS name_or_nationality FROM owners
SELECT id, IF(name, name, nationality) AS name_or_nationality FROM owners
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with simple `if /else` condition in your query .

like below :

```
SELECT id,if(name='',nationality,name) as ownerinfo FROM owners
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL select statement will return a value if name is null:

```
SELECT id,
       case when ifnull(name,'') = '' 
       then nationality 
       else name 
       end as name_equiv
FROM owners;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that your values are set to NULL and not just blank:

```
SELECT IF(name IS NULL, nationality, name) AS name_or_nationality FROM owners
```

For an explanation of conditional statements in MySQL:
http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/13/inline-if-and-case-statements-in-mysql/